# Specific parameters in GET- request: don't doing 301 redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I replaced the addresses of all pages that contain `.html` in the end of the URL to addresses that do not contain `.html`.

`.htaccess` (relevant part):

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
...
```

For example, instead of this address:

```
http://......net/part0/part1/part2/part3.html
```

I get this address:

```
http://......net/part0/part1/part2/part3
```

Now I need don't perform a redirect (I should return code `200`) if GET request contains some specific parameters, such as:

```
?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

Ie this query:

```
http://......net/part0/part1/part2/part3.html?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

Should be converted to this query:

```
http://......net/part0/part1/part2/part3?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

How can I do it?

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Comment: IMHO, if you need to change the URL, you must have a redirection (which isn't necessarily a 301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .html extension

# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```